# How to specify Typescript Mongoose model type in await

Tags: typescript, mongoose, async-await

I have to save a user in user model

```
            const userDoc: Document =  new User(user);
            const userData: UserModel  = await userDoc.save();
```

the below warning is coming when i specify type on userdata

Type 'Document' is not assignable to type 'UserModel'.
Type 'Document' is not assignable to type '{ email: string; password: String; phone: Number; verificationToken: String; emailVerified: Boole...'.
    Property 'email' is missing in type 'Document'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [the declaration of `save`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/98408751da3708a6f7a796c7259950415b1f8b1b/types/mongoose/index.d.ts#L2921), it returns a promise for the same type as the object on which it is called:

```
save(options?: SaveOptions, fn?: (err: any, product: this) => void): Promise<this>;
```

Thus, declaring `userDoc` as type `User` or `UserModel` or just removing the type annotation on `userDoc` should help.

Comment: const userDoc: UserModel Helped